# Autoreply in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

So I found a code that automaticall sends a reply everytime someone fills up my google form, informing them that they have successfulyl registered for the event, etc. The mail is usually sent to the email that these guys provide in the form and I have labelled that field as "email" (with lower caps). here is the code

```
 function sendAutoreply(e)  
{  
  var myemail = "rahil27@gmail.com";
  var email="";  
  var subject="Re: Confirmation Email - Teacher Development";   
  var message = "Thank you for registering for Teacher Development. This is to confirm your registration for Thursday 24th December, 2012 \n\n-----\n\n";  

 try {

    for(var field in e) 
 {  
    message += field + ' :: '  
               + e.namedValues[field].toString() + "\n\n";  
    if (field == 'email') {  
      email = e.namedValues[field].toString();  
    }  
    if (field == 'name') {  
      subject += e.namedValues[field].toString();  
    }  

  }

  // We are using JavaScript MailApp util of Google Apps Script  
  // that sends the email.  

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {replyTo:myemail});  
} catch(e){  
    MailApp.sendEmail(myemail, "Error in Auto replying to contact form submission. No reply was sent.", e.message);  
  }  
}
```

**It throws me an error: Cannot read property "namedValues" from undefined.**

Please help !

Comment: you have tagged your question as GWT. How is it related to GWT?

Answer (score 0):

When you test in the debugger, no parameter is passed to your function. Since it's expecting `e`, you get an `undefined` error.

See [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas).